# An efficient way to print a string to a file

Tags: c

I have a

```
char* aString
```

and I want to write the portion of `aString` between `from` and `to`, what is the most efficient way?

I think of a way which writes 1 characters at a time.

```
char* p = aString + from;
for (int i =0; i < (to-from); i++) {
    fprintf(aFile, "%c", p++);
}
```

I wonder if there is a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fwrite as follows:

```
char *s = "abcdef";

fwrite(s,sizeof(char),2,stdout); // prints ab

fwrite(s+2,sizeof(char),2,stdout); // prints cd

// In general
fwrite(s+from,sizeof(char),to-from,stdout); // print char bet s[from] to s[to]
```

If you want to write to a file you can replace stdout with the corresponding file pointer.

Answer (score 6):

fwrite

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/

Answer (score 6):

Don is right that fwrite is the quickest.

That said, here's a little know feature of printf (and snprintf, vprintf, etc.) that allows you to do it in one call.

```
printf("%.*s", to - from, aString + from);
```

How this works.  Providing a precision for a string says print no more then that many characters (it can print less if it finds a '\0' first).  So a line like:

```
printf("%.5s", "0123456789");
```

will print:

```
01234
```

Next, if you need to specify your precision at runtime, replacing the number with a * and provide the length as a function parameter before the string:

```
printf("%.*s", 5, "0123456789");  // same as before
```

If all you want to do is print the one part of the string this trick is overkill.  But in combination with other formatting, it can be quite helpful:

```
printf("Token %d: \"%.*s\"\n",
       tok,
       token_info[tok].len,
       str + token_info[tok].start);
```

Comment: I doubt this technique. In my experience, printf() does not truncate arguments in this situation. The man page says: "In no case does a non-existent or small field width cause truncation of a field; if the result of a conversion is wider than the field width, the field is expanded to contain the conversion result" (from http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Comment: @unwind: You're reading the wrong section.  It's the *precision* that's being specified, not the the field width, and the precision has special behavior for `%s`.

Comment: @unwind - as jamesdlin correctly states, you are referring to the field width while I was describing the precision.  When specifying just the field width no period is used; when specifying both field width and precision, the field width comes before the period while the precision comes after.